# Group template parameters in C++

Tags: c++, templates, constexpr

I'm building a number-of-dimensions-independent algorithm, where the number of dimensions is a template parameter. I have a number of input and a number of output dimensions.

For 5 input dimensions and 3 output dimensions, ideally, this looks like this:

```cpp
my_algorithm<5, 3> algo;
```

However, I very often need the sum of the input and output dimensions. So what I came up with is:

```cpp
template <size_t IDims, size_t ODims = 3, size_t Dims = IDims + ODims>
class my_algorithm;
```

This way, the total number of dimensions is also a compile time constant. Note that the most usual scenario has only 3 output dimensions, so I put that as a default argument. This allows me very nicely:

```cpp
my_algorithm<5> algo;
```

However, not I have this very long template signature I have to write down for every method in this class. For example:

```cpp
template <size_t IDims, size_t ODims, size_t Dims>
my_algorithm<IDims, ODims, Dims>::prepare(size_t k, size_t Kcap) {
    m_Kcap = Kcap;
    m_pi = new float[Kcap]{1.0f / k};
}
```

I really don't like this, and was wondering if there is an elegant way to group these template parameters together in some sort of struct. I came up with a mini test like this:

```cpp
#include <cstdio>

template<size_t IDims, size_t ODims = 3>
struct Dims {
    static constexpr size_t I = IDims;
    static constexpr size_t O = ODims;
    static constexpr size_t A = I + O;
};

template<typename D>
void function() {
    std::printf("function() with Dims<%zu, %zu, %zu>\n", D::I, D::O, D::A);
}

int main() {
    function<Dims<2, 4>>();
    function<Dims<2>>();
    return 0;
}
```

Now I only have one argument to include (`typename D`), but I don't like how you could literally plug in everything there, instead of only a Dims struct.

Comment: seems easily fixed by a `static_assert` or `enable_if`, or use a functor instead of a function, with `operator()` and specialize it only for `Dims`.

Comment: Using the sum of the input and output dimensions as another template argument is a bad idea. It allows you to instantiate `my_algorithm<5, 3, 10>`, which does not make sense.

Comment: If a type passed to `function` provides static constants `I`, `O` and `A`, what are the odds that was a mistake? I think that being able to pass any type that provides the correct interface to be an advantage, not a disadvantage.

Comment: `IDims + ODims` is a compile-time constant, you don't need to put it into a template parameter.

Comment: @pschill: Ye I know, but I won't do that. It's to avoid having to write in every function: `constexpr size_t Dims = IDims + ODims` and I would kinda like to avoid a preprocessor macro, although `#define Dims (IDims + ODims)` would probably work great.

Comment: You could also write `static constexpr size_t Dims = IDims + ODims;` at class scope.

Comment: Just to give you an idea of what the possible solutions mentioned by Nicolas Holthaus could look like : https://ideone.com/mne1l0 (the enable_if can also be in the return type, it has the benefit of not introducing a template parameter the user could mess up with, but the downside of being less readable imo). I'm sure there are other solutions as well.

Answer (score 0):

I went with the approach posted in the question. The only annoying thing about is that it requires C++17, as the `constexpr static` members of the `Dims` struct are not inlined always. It's a bit weird. In some situations it was fixable by first extracting it to a local `constexpr` like so:

```
template<typename D>
void my_algo<D>::some_function(size_t number) {
    constexpr DA = D::A;
    Eigen::Matrix<float, D::A, Eigen::Dynamic> vector (DA, number);
    //                   ^^^^                          ^^
    //                   works                 here D::A doesn't work
}
```

The reported error with `D::A` is that the linker cannot find the symbol. C++17 now implicitly inlines these `static constexpr`, so they are not longer needed by the linker, as they are fully present in the object file itself.